# Finding the roots of two lines using brentq

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to write a function which returns the x value of some data when the y value is approximately zero. I am given two lists to enter in to the function as [1,4,5] for x values and [-3,5,9] for y values for example. I have written this function by using interpolation and then using indexing to first find index of the y value when it is closes to zero and using this to find the x value at this point: (please note: I added the graph and the y = 0 line for illustrative purposes only.)

```
def root(xs, ys):
    xfine = np.linspace(min(xs), max(xs), 10000)
    y0 = inter.interp1d(xs, ys, kind = 'linear')
    f1 = xfine, y0(xfine)
    x2fine = np.linspace(min(xs), max(xs), 10000)
    y2 = np.linspace(0,0, 10000)
    f2 = x2fine, y2
    pl.plot(xfine, y0(xfine))
    pl.plot(x2fine, y2)
    pl.show()
    closest = min(abs(y0(xfine)))
    xindex = numpy.searchsorted(y0(xfine), closest)
    print round(xfine[xindex], 3)
```

This appears to be giving me the right answers but I am told I should use brentq in my function. However I am only given data like that mentioned above, and I swear brentq needs two continuous functions entered doesn't it? How can I go about making this work for brentq with only a new numbers instead of a function?

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use brentq on the interpolated function, since you are already using interpolation, just use it to invert the function:

```
finv = inter.interp1d(y, x)
print (finv(0))
```